# Looping through an arraylist sourced from an XML file

Tags: apache-flex

I am reading in an XML file that is shown in the attached image. I'm reading it in using URLRequest, which works properly. The next thing I'd like to do is to populate an arraylist with all of the "project" nodes. I'm converting the XML to an array, but the source is showing the project as being in the [0] node and the arraylist's length is 1.

[image] [image]

What's the proper way to do this so I can loop through all the projects in the arraylist?

```
private var xmlParameters:XML
private var xmlStoryMap:XMLList;

protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var params:Object;
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlloader_onComplete_Handler);
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,IOError_handler);

    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("myXML.xml"));    
}

protected function xmlloader_onComplete_Handler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target)

    xmlParameters = new XML(loader.data);
    xmlStoryMap = xmlParameters.projects;

    initializeMap();
}

protected function initializeMap():void
{
    var testlist:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
    testlist.source = convertXMLtoArray(xmlStoryMap.project);

}

private function convertXMLtoArray(file:String):Array
{
    var xml:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(file);
    var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder;
    var data:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xml);
    var array:Array = ArrayUtil.toArray(data);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Consider using XMLListCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have a loop issue, use this instead

```
        protected function xmlloader_onComplete_Handler(event:Event):void
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target)
            var xmlString:String = loader.data;

            initializeMap(xmlString);
        }

        protected function initializeMap(xmlString:String):void
        {
            var testlist:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
            testlist.source = convertXMLtoArray(xmlString);
        }

        private function convertXMLtoArray(xmlString:String):Array
        {
            var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(xmlString);
            var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder();
            var data:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);

            return ArrayUtil.toArray(data.storymap.projects.project);
        }
```

Comment: Is it really neccessary to convert XML object to String and then parse it back to Object? Wouldn't it be wise to change convertXMLtoArray parameter type and pass XML or (what is IMHO better) do it all in one function.

Comment: Yes you are right, the conversion XML->String is not necessary. I would do it with String. Whether or not do all in one function is the question of the developer. "ConvertXMLToArray" can be reused in some cases. I have corrected my answer, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

For looping through the projects,

```
for each(var projectXML:XML in  xmlParameters.projects.project)
{
     // Do operation
}
```